# Nouns following the verb "turn"

Tags: agreement

I am wondering why we use a singilar noun in the following construction:

-The two brothers turned "terrorist".

Is there any explanation for using the singular form?

Comment: It is the class, not the individual, that is referred to by the noun here. This question has been dealt with earlier on these pages. See previous related posts.